How do I find weight functions expression?
Suppose we have 2 restrictions for low frequencies and 1 restriction for high frequencies, restrictions being:

$|L| > a$ for w $\in$ [0, $w_1$) radians/s
$|L| > b$ for w $\in$ [0, $w_2$) radians/s
$|L| < c$ for w $\in$ ($w_3$, $\infty$) radians/s,

where L is a SISO transfer function in open loop, $a > b > 1 > c > 0$ and $w_1 < w_2 < w_3$.
From these 3 restrictions, how do I determine the weight functions $W_S$ and $W_T$, where $W_S$ is the weight associated with performance/ the weight high on low frequencies, and $W_T$ is the weight associated with model uncertainties/ the weight high on high frequencies. And how do I determine these weights such as they are well defined/ they satisfy the inequality
$min(|W_S|,|W_T|)<1,\forall w$?
